# Storing and comparing UTC times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, momentjs, moment-timezone

Say this is the current server time in UTC `2021-07-30 00:33:25 UTC`, which in local time is just `2021-07-29 5:33 PM`
25 hours from that time is `2021-07-31 01:33:25 UTC`, which in local time is `2021-07-30 6:33 PM`
The stored time being compared is saved as `2021-07-30T19:00:00+00:00`, which in local time should be `2021-07-30 7:00 PM`

The problem is that the stored time should be `2021-07-31T02:00:00+00:00` to equal `2021-07-30 7:00 PM`,
but I'm not sure of the best approach to get that time.

Here's how I get the time being sent to my rails backend

```
  import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
  ...
  const start_time = moment
    .tz(
      listingAvailability.listing_availability_ranges_attributes[0]
        .start_time,
      'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'
    )
    .tz('America/Phoenix')
    .toISOString(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with

```
moment.utc(moment(listingAvailabilityTime).utc().local()).format();
```